# Java: How to have one array reference the start of another?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, element, wav

Im trying to make a fun application that will take a sound file and modify it, and create a new sound file.

One of the things I am trying to do is make the sound file twice as long. So I essentially make a new array that goes {2,2,3,3,7,7,8,8} instead of the original {2,3,7,8}. I am using doubles, this is simply an example

I want the original array (samples) to now reference the start of the array I just created (temp) so when the file saves it now save the temp array.

I can increase or decrease the volume of the music file no problem, and save it as such. I omitted that part of the code as it is not pertinent here.

If anyone is kind enough to help me, I also want to know the why behind it

public class Sound {

```
double[] samples;
    //So we only have to declare it once. Reference to an array

public Sound() {
    //This constructor should initialize the samples array to be empty

    samples = new double[0];
        //Initialize an array with nothing because we will be using that to reference the    
        //location of other arrays

}

public void wavRead(String fileName) {

    samples = WavIO.read(fileName);
        //Samples was an adress of an array we set to 0. Then we used WavIO to create an aray of doubles, now 
        //we tell samples to reference this new address over here. Samples has the addsss of the new array

}

public void wavSave(String fileName) {

    WavIO.write(fileName, samples);

}

    public void lengthen() {

     double[] temp = new double[(samples.length *2)];

      int t = 0;

     for(int i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {


            //Set a variable to increase the temp array by

         temp[t] = samples[i];
            //Have position 0 of temp = position 0 of soundRaw

         t++;
            //Increase the position in the temp array by one

         temp[t] = samples[i];
            //Have position 1 of temp array = position 0 of soundRaw

     }

     samples[0] = temp;
        //Here is where I try and have the samples array reference the start of another array. I tried multiple things, this is simply the last effort I tried

}
```

**And here is the application I am using to test the code**

public class App {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Sound s = new Sound();
        //We are now calling the other code

    s.wavRead("bye8");
        //If you want to mess with your own .wav file, replace this name

    s.lengthen();

    s.wavSave("bye8New");

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing this code line

```
  samples[0] = temp;
```

with just

```
 samples = temp;
```

will suffice! :)

Comment: I tried that earlier and the sound was quiet for the second half. But upon redoing what you said I realized I never incremented t once more so the code is now how I intended it to be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`DoubleBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/DoubleBuffer.html), it is much easier to do what you want to achieve.

To create a new `DoubleBuffer` which is... Double... The size and duplicates, you'll then do:

```
// Important!
origBuf.rewind();

final DoubleBuffer newBuf = DoubleBuffer.allocate(origBuf.remaining() * 2);

double value;

while (origBuf.hasRemaining()) {
    value = origBuf.get();
    newBuf.put(value).put(value);
}
```

Then `newBuf.array()` will return the `double[]` array "with duplicates".

Also note that a `DoubleBuffer`, like any `XBuffer`, allows you to set endianness.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `samples=temp;` instead of `samples[0] = temp;`!